# Want a simple kubernetes rabbitmq cluster yaml with erlang cookie being passed without any user issue

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, cluster-analysis

Current Yaml:

```yaml
---------------
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq1
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
    name: amqp
  - port: 15672
    targetPort: 15672
    name: management
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq1

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq1
        image: rabbitmq:3.10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: amqp
        - containerPort: 15672
          name: management
        env:
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
          value: "guest"
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
          value: "guest"
        # volumeMounts:
        # - name: rabbitlib
        #   mountPath: "/var/lib/rabbitmq/"
      # volumes:
      # - name: rabbitlib
      #   emptyDir: {}
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        - |
          echo "VOLPAY" > /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
          chmod 600 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 6Gi
-----------
Issue - /bin/bash: echo "VOLPAY" > /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
chmod 600 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
: No such file or directory
```

erlang cookie file should pass without any issues and rabbit server should start properly

Comment: Are you missing a `bash -c` option?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by giving the following:

```
    command: 
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
      mkdir /var/lib/rabbitmq
      touch /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
      echo "test" > /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
      chmod 400 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
      chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
      rabbitmq-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a command to create the cookie file; use a secret (mounted to the correct path).

The RabbitMQ blog recommends using a secret and mounting it from there; see https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2020/08/deploying-rabbitmq-to-kubernetes-whats-involved/#node-authentication-secret-the-erlang-cookie.

Comment: This does not contain the info of where the .erlang file permission issue is to be solved. can you please refer me to the appropriate link ?

Comment: There is no permission issue; the secret is mounted _as that file_.

Comment: thanks for the response, how should i rectify the code to make it work?